# RavenDB sql query which run automaticly

Tags: ravendb

I'm wondering if in ravendb is possible to implement such a functionallity:
I have some query (for example update query) and i want to run it every 1st of the month. 
Anyone knows way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout CRON jobs.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

I won't downvote / flag since you probably didn't know you were looking for a cron jobs. For future reference please try to google for questions like this first though.

If this is windows based, Sechduled Tasks are more up your ally I assume.

If neither of those works have your application track the last time the command ran and then run it if 1 months has expired. Is this a web app?

If so you can embed it in you application controller and hope someone hits the page near the 1 month mark.